# How can I access to each field of a json object?

Tags: javascript

I have used csvtojson in order to write the csv data into a sql database, the object that the funcion return to have this structure:

```js
var prueba = [
  {'Aula;Capacidad': 'A10+11;112'},
  {'Aula;Capacidad': 'A12;66' }
];
```

How can I acces to each field? I am trying to do `console.log(prueba[0]["Capacidad"])` in order to see if it is running but it prints "undefined".

Comment: Is this an SQL or JavaScript question? It's not entirely clear from your question if you want to access this data in an SQL query or purely from JavaScript?

Comment: You are going to have to parse that....

Comment: `Capacidad` doesn't exist as a property for the first element in the array. You need to change your code to `prueba[0]["Aula;Capacidad"]`

Comment: Thanks for your comments, i have just wanted to access to "Capacidad" and "Aula" separately because when i convert my csv it to json the result was that array. The final solution is down this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key you are looking up is in a composite key. So you would need to look it up with that composite key and than split it.

```js
var prueba = [
  {'Aula;Capacidad': 'A10+11;112'},
  {'Aula;Capacidad': 'A12;66' }
];

console.log(prueba[0]['Aula;Capacidad'].split(";")[1]);
```

Other choice is to parse it all and look it up by the key.

```js
var prueba = [
  {'Aula;Capacidad': 'A10+11;112'},
  {'Aula;Capacidad': 'A12;66' }
];

const parsed = prueba.reduce(function (arr, row) {
  const entry = Object.entries(row)[0];
  const keys = entry[0].split(";");
  const values = entry[1].split(";");
  const data = keys.reduce(function (o, key, index) {
    o[key] = values[index];
    return o;
  }, {}); 
  arr.push(data);
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(parsed[0].Capacidad);
console.log(parsed[1].Capacidad);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it really helps me, my final solution is the next :

Comment: for(var i =0;i<prueba.length;i++){
            var aula = prueba[i]['Aula;Capacidad'].split(";")[0];
            var capacidad = prueba[i]['Aula;Capacidad'].split(";")[1];
            var values = [aula,capacidad];
            //console.log("aula",i,"--",aula,"capacidad--",capacidad);
            console.log("vector de valores -->",values);
            mysqlConnection.query("INSERT INTO aulas (nombre_aula,capacidad) VALUES ?",[values],(err,res)=>{
                if(err) throw err;
                console.log("1 record inserted");
            })

Answer (score 1):

'Aula;Capacidad' is seen as a key, so you only can do the following:

```
console.log(prueba[0]["Aula;Capacidad])
```

which will write

```
A10+11;112
```

to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Your properties are actually named 'Aula;Capacidad', meaning you'd need to use `prueba[0]['Aula;Capacidad']` to get the value you are looking for.

This is what you need to iterate through the list of items:

```
var prueba = [{'Aula;Capacidad': 'A10+11;112'},{'Aula;Capacidad': 'A12;66' }]; 
for (var i = 0; i < prueba.length; i++) {
    console.log(prueba[i]);
}
```

If you need to go deeper and iterate over every item properties:

```
var prueba = [{'Aula;Capacidad': 'A10+11;112'},{'Aula;Capacidad': 'A12;66' }]; 
for(var i = 0; i < prueba.length; i++) {
    for(var p in prueba[0]) {
        console.log(p, prueba[i][p]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks malformed so you might need to do some manual processing.

You have an array of two items, both with a single key-value in them. You can do `console.log(prueba[0]["Aula;Capacidad"])` and this will return `'A10+11;112'`.

You might need to split things by the `;` there so you could do something like this:

```js
var prueba = [
  {'Aula;Capacidad': 'A10+11;112'},
  {'Aula;Capacidad': 'A12;66' }
];

prueba.forEach(item => {
  const splitItem = item["Aula;Capacidad"].split(";");
  console.log("Each item now looks like this: " + splitItem)
  
  // You can access the first and second part of the item like this
  console.log(splitItem[0], splitItem[1])
})
```

To be honest, I'd go back and look at how this data is being added to your DB. It looks messed up.

Comment: Thanks for your comment it really helps me to understand that i should use .split to separate the data and then introduce it in my database.